# Inlining in API requests and responses

Tags: json, language-agnostic, schema

I'll represent my question in JSON, but any interfacing language could apply here.

```
POST '/api/dog'

{
    id: 1,
    age: 8,
    breed: 11
    // Passing the breed name here doesn't make sense, 
    //   since we don't want to assign the breedName to the breed id
}

GET '/api/dog/1'

{
    // Retrieving the id here doesn't make sense,
    //   since we asked for it in our request
    age: 8,
    breed: 11,
    breedName: 'Golden Retriever'
}
```

Another option would be to return a dictionary along with your object. This works well for collections, but is awkward for single results.

```
GET '/api/dog'

{
    dogs: [
        {
            id: 1, // not needed for ordered collections
            age: 8,
            breed: 11
        },
        {
            id: 2,
            age: 3,
            breed: 4
        },
        {
            id: 3,
            age: 3,
            breed: 11
        }
    ],

    breeds: [
        {
            id: 4,
            name: 'Chiwawa'
        },
        {
            id: 11,
            name: 'Golden Retriever'
        }
    ]
}
```

Certainly, this issue isn't restricted to names either - there always seems to be a decision regarding whether to inline large objects or just their ids. With a cyclic structure (ie a network graph linked by urls), it would be impossible to always inline. Likewise it would be costly to never inline.

Since there are inevitable tradeoffs, I'd like to learn what the best practices are.

- Do API designers use the same schema for input and output? If so, do
  they omit elements when not necessary?
- Should the outgoing schema extend the incoming schema (or vice versa) to accomodate inlining?
- When (if ever) should a dictionary be used?
- Should dictionary data be managed by a separate API call?

I am looking for guidelines people have found helpful, but any theoretical answer would be useful to me as well.